# Make a API call in JUnit with Kotlin

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, rx-java2, dagger-2

I am beginner in automatic test so I wanna to make an API call to update some data on backend and I wanna to test that with JUnit4. The problem is when I wanna to subscribe make that call he throw NPE.

My test class looks like:

```
class PhoneNumberPresenterTest {
    @Mock
    private val userService: UserService? = null

    val testScheduler = TestScheduler()

    val scheduler = TestSchedulerProvider(testScheduler)

@Before
    fun setup() {
//init stuffs
}
        @Test
    fun onContinueClicked_ResponseSuccess() {
        val phoneNumber = "(01234567890)"

        val genericResponse = GenericResponse<CheckApprovedStatusResponse>()
        genericResponse.data = CheckApprovedStatusResponse()

        `when`(userService!!.checkUserApprovedStatus(phoneNumber)).thenReturn(just(genericResponse))

        presenter!!.onContinueClicked(phoneNumber)

        testScheduler.triggerActions()
        ///stuffs
}
```

And here is where I POST my user data on backend in Presenter

```
class PhoneNumberPresenter(private var mView: PhoneNumberContract.View,
                           private var scheduler: SchedulerProvider) : PhoneNumberContract.Handler {

 override fun onContinueClicked(enteredPhoneNumber: String) {
        mUserService.checkUserApprovedStatus(phoneNumber)
                .subscribeOn(scheduler.io())
                .observeOn(scheduler.ui())
                .subscribe({ response ->
                }, { error ->
                })
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

mUserService.checkUserApprovedStatus(phoneNumber) is null

Answer (score 0):

The idea is quite simple here. You have to provide a scheduler inside your presenter (or whatever class):

```
interface YourSchedulerProvider {
    fun io(): Scheduler
    fun ui(): Scheduler
}

class YourPresenter
@Inject constructor(
        val scheduler: YourSchedulerProvider) {

   fun someFun() {
    mUserService.updateUser(id!!,accessToken!!,user)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler.io())
            .observeOn(scheduler.ui())
            .subscribe({ _ ->}, { _->})
   }
```

and in your Dagger just provide some serious implementation of YourSchedulerProvider.

Than in tests just provide:

```
class YourTestSchedulerProvider(private val scheduler: Scheduler) : YourSchedulerProvider {

    override fun io(): Scheduler {
        return scheduler
    }

    override fun ui(): Scheduler {
        return scheduler
    }

    override fun computation(): Scheduler {
        return scheduler
    }
}
```

And use this in your unit tests, like:

```
val testScheduler = TestScheduler()
val scheduler = YourTestSchedulerProvider(testScheduler)
val presenter = YourPresenter(..., scheduler)

@Test
fun test() {
    (...)
    presenter.someFun()
    testScheduler.triggerActions()
}
```

Comment: " .subscribeOn(scheduler.io())" give me nullPointerException. have you an ideea why?

Comment: I'd guess scheduler is null. Check if it injects correctly inside of your presenter

Comment: it`s not null but size, counter, time is 0. May be that a problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's just impossible to give you any kind of answer here. I do not know what kind of "size, counter, time" you are writing about. But if you are 100% sure that NPE is from that specific line, than its probably due to null scheduler or null observable that you are calling .subsctibeOn on. And this error is probably not necessary connected with this suggested solution. It's rather implementation issue